# Test for causal mechanism via difference in coefficients after adding intervening variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

There is a general heuristic for checking whether a variable is involved in the causal impact by seeing how much adding that variable as a control changes the magnitude of the coefficient on the treatment variable.  I'm sure I saw at some point a seminar presentation discussing a statistical method for testing how meaningful the change in magnitude is, but I haven't been able to find the paper or any reference to it.
The only similar mention I've seen is in a comparison of different approaches to test intervening variable effects, but the citations related to the difference in coefficient approach there, are older and not from economics. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2819363/pdf/nihms-173350.pdf
I specifically want to use this approach to compare coefficients for a causal impact estimated using an IV approach, and would like to know if there is any guidance for what is a meaningful difference in coefficients that suggests a causal pathway.

Comment: Are you aiming to test whether including an intervening variable changes the causal effect or whether including a confounding variable changes the causal effect?

Comment: Hi Noah, we want to test whether an intervening variable changes the causal effect.  We find that adding a specific intervening variable reduces the magnitude of the causal effect to the extent that it loses significance, and would like to say something about the degree to which this implies that the mechanism of action is coming only through that intervening variable vs. through other mechanisms.